# ASIFormDataRequest uploads blank image

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest, image-uploading

After searching here for a simple image upload with ASIFormDataRequest i finally got it working(sort of) but with a unexpected error.

My image is uploaded to my server but it is **blank**, 0 bytes in size. 
Here is my code:

```
 -(IBAction)uploadImage:(id)sender
{
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image,0.6f);
    NSString *file = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload.png"];
    [data writeToFile:file atomically:YES];

    NSString *strURL = @"http://domain.com/upload.php";

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageNamed:file];
    NSData *imageData1=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 1.0);
    [request setData:imageData1 withFileName:file andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"avatar"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    //[request appendPostData:body];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:13.0];
    request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload ok: \"%@\"",[request responseString]);
}

- (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]);

}
```

**My PHP code:**

```
<?php 

 $target = "./"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['avatar']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file ok";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }

?>
```

At first i thought it was a folder permision thing but i tested it with a simple html form upload(with the same php file,unedited) and the file was uploaded in full size.

I know that such a method of uploading a file is dangerous,but for the moment it is the only thing i got.

Any ideas why my file it's not getting uploaded?
Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that ASIHTTPRequest is no longer being maintained, and hasn't had an update since 2011?

Comment: yes i'm fully aware but this doesn't stop (so many) people using it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,i followed your advise and actually used AFNetwork
Here is my code for helping out others.

```
    NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 0.5f);
    AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"upload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"avatar" fileName:fullFilename mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *response = [operation responseString];
        NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if([operation.response statusCode] == 403){
            NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

    }];

    [operation start];
```